# Customize day AntD calendar

Tags: antd

I need to customize day name in AntD calendar. For Sunday, instead "Su" needs to show "Sun". Is there any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ant Design Calendar: How to Change the Day of Week Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069572/ant-design-calendar-how-to-change-the-day-of-week-format)

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually change each `th` and `span` content. you can change the code as per your need.

[image: pic]

**styles.css**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

/* sunday */
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(1)>span{
  display: none;
}
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(1):after{
  content: "Sun";
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* monday */
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(2)>span{
  display: none;
}
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(2):after{
  content: "Mon";
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* tuesday */
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(3)>span{
  display: none;
}
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(3):after{
  content: "Tue";
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* wednesday */
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(4)>span{
  display: none;
}
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(4):after{
  content: "Wed";
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* thursday */
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(5)>span{
  display: none;
}
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(5):after{
  content: "Thu";
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* friday */
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(6)>span{
  display: none;
}
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(6):after{
  content: "Fri";
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* saturday */
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(7)>span{
  display: none;
}
.ant-fullcalendar.ant-fullcalendar-full>div>table>thead>
tr th:nth-child(7):after{
  content: "Sat";
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Here is the code sandbox. Change the code as per your need.[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-calender-58406824-9c3zm) . Hope it helps.

[antd calender](https://ant.design/components/calendar/)

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by setting the information I wanted on the correct property using momentjs:

```
<Calendar 
   locale={{ 
      lang: { 
         locale: 'en', 
         dayFormat: moment.updateLocale('en', { 
                    weekdaysMin: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ]
         }) 
       } 
    }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to change to portuguese, for example, here's what have worked for me:

(Also, before that, it's important to use a 'wrapper' class in DatePicker in order to reach the desired elements. To do that, I used a class called 'pt-datepicker', in the following way)

```
<DatePicker dropdownClassName="pt-datepicker" />
```

Read more about 'dropdownClassName' here: https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#Common-API

And now, the SCSS to change the label of each week day:

```
.pt-datepicker {
  .ant-picker-panel-container {
    .ant-picker-panel {
      .ant-picker-date-panel {
        .ant-picker-body {
          .ant-picker-content {
            thead {
              tr {
                th:nth-child(1) {
                  visibility: hidden;
                  position: relative;
                }

                th:nth-child(1):after {
                  visibility: visible;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  left: 50%;
                  content: 'Dom';
                  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                th:nth-child(2) {
                  visibility: hidden;
                  position: relative;
                }

                th:nth-child(2):after {
                  visibility: visible;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  left: 50%;
                  content: 'Seg';
                  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                th:nth-child(3) {
                  visibility: hidden;
                  position: relative;
                }

                th:nth-child(3):after {
                  visibility: visible;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  left: 50%;
                  content: 'Ter';
                  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                th:nth-child(4) {
                  visibility: hidden;
                  position: relative;
                }

                th:nth-child(4):after {
                  visibility: visible;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  left: 50%;
                  content: 'Qua';
                  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                th:nth-child(5) {
                  visibility: hidden;
                  position: relative;
                }

                th:nth-child(5):after {
                  visibility: visible;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  left: 50%;
                  content: 'Qui';
                  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                th:nth-child(6) {
                  visibility: hidden;
                  position: relative;
                }

                th:nth-child(6):after {
                  visibility: visible;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  left: 50%;
                  content: 'Sex';
                  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                th:nth-child(7) {
                  visibility: hidden;
                  position: relative;
                }

                th:nth-child(7):after {
                  visibility: visible;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  left: 50%;
                  content: 'Sab';
                  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```